# Problems with iterating 'int' values when converting for loop to while loop

Tags: python

I have been set the task of creating a program that extracts data from a text file between 2 key words using a while loop creating a list of tuples (with the date being as a list and the data value as an integer)

E.g.

```
<begin step data>
2001-01-01,12776
2001-01-02,15128
<end step data>
```

extract it into format like `[('2001-01-01', 12776), ('2001-01-02', 15128)]`

I started off by solving it with a `for` loop to make it easier, I ended up with this piece of code which gives me the right answer:

```
def read_records_from_file(filename):

    """ bla """

    mylist = []
    line = open(filename).read()
    start = '<begin step data>'
    end = '<end step data>'
    startpos = line.find(start) + len(start)
    endpos = line.find(end, startpos)
    data = line[startpos:endpos]
    mylist.append(data.split())

    desired = []
    for element in mylist[0]:
        element = element.split(',')

        desired.append((element[0],int(element[1])))  

    return desired
```

This is my approach to converting it to a while loop:

```
def read_records_from_file(filename):

    """ bla """

    mylist = []
    line = open(filename).read()
    start = '<begin step data>'
    end = '<end step data>'
    startpos = line.find(start) + len(start)
    endpos = line.find(end, startpos)
    data = line[startpos:endpos]
    mylist.append(data.split())

    desired = []

    element = 0

    while element < len(mylist[0]):
        element = element.split(',')
        desired.append((element[0],int(element[1]))) 
        element += 1

    return desired
```

But this gives me an errors `'int' object has no attribute 'split'`. I am confused how me changing it to a while loop is making it read it as an `int` instead of a `list`.

Comment: element containing integer value. You can not split the int value.

Comment: Then why does it work as a for loop?

Comment: Because in for loop you have not mentioned element = 0. In for loop it is taking actual data

Comment: for element in mylist[0]: This sentence means element containing actual data (one by one) not the index.

Comment: I have updated my answer, for using the while

Answer (score 2):

`For` statement can be converted in `while` as:

```
element = 0
while element < len(mylist[0]):
    data = mylist[0][element].split(',')
    desired.append((data[0],int(data[1]))) 
    element += 1
```

You can try the Pythonic way:

```
>>> data = "2001-01-01,12776 2001-01-02,15128"
>>> data = data.split()
>>> print data
['2001-01-01,12776', '2001-01-02,15128']
>>> final_data = []
>>> for d in data:
    temp = tuple(d.split(","))
    temp_tuple = (temp[0],int(temp[1]))
    final_data.append(temp_tuple)   

>>> print final_data
[('2001-01-01', '12776'), ('2001-01-02', '15128')]
```

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention importantly that the data value needs to be an int and the date should remain as a list.

Comment: Thank you very much! looks like i need to study up on while loops!

Comment: @JayDilla : You can easily convert string into int. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
st = "2001-01-01,12776 2001-01-02,15128"
final_list = []
for elem in st.split():
   date = elem.split(",")[0]
   data = elem.split(",")[-1]
   final_list.append((date, int(data)))
print final_list
```

You can also use this code to generate your output.